# For loop in VBScript (QTP) not functioning

Tags: for-loop, vbscript, iterator, qtp

I'm using QTP 11.0 which uses VBScript for it's "language".

I have the following four lines of code:

```
For x = 1 to 8
msgbox(x)
update1 =  SwfWindow("NextGen File Maintenance").SwfWindow("SIM Library Configuration").SwfObject("spreadCtl").Object.ActiveSheet.GetValue(x,2)
Next
```

The return values are:

1
3
3
3
3
3
...  forever

I can not seem to use the counter variable in a vbscript for loop without it somehow becoming corrupted - no matter what the name of the variable.  I have even tried assigning X to another variable and using that in my GetValue statement with no success.

Am I missing something really simple here?  No documentation on Google for a vbscript For loop implies any different usage.  I found nothing in reference to QTP either.

Thanks,

Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very strange, I assume that if you remove the second line in the loop and just leave the `MsgBox` then `x` is incremented correctly.

Perhaps `ActiveSheet.GetValue` takes the first parameter by reference and modifies it. You say that you tried using a temporary variable and it didn't work, have you tried something like this?

```
For x = 1 to 8
    tmp = x
    update1 =  SwfWindow("NextGen File Maintenance").SwfWindow("SIM Library Configuration").SwfObject("spreadCtl").Object.ActiveSheet.GetValue(tmp, 2)
    MsgBox("x=" & x & " tmp=" & tmp)
Next
```

If the problem is that `GetValue` indeed changes the index you can try using a function that takes the index by value and then use that in the loop.

```
Public Function GetVal(ByVal index)
       GetVal = SwfWindow("NextGen File Maintenance").SwfWindow("SIM Library Configuration").SwfObject("spreadCtl").Object.ActiveSheet.GetValue(index, 2)
End Function
```

Comment: It appears that the GetValue method is causing the issue.  I can create a for next loop that uses the counter value in other statements just fine.   Of course I can't find where to log a defect with HP so it looks like I'm just going to have to write out 8 sections of repeatable code.. :-(

Comment: @Jason if `GetValue` is causing the issue then the problem is (probably) in the application you're testing not with QTP, you are after all using `.Object` which means you're working directly on the objects in the tested application. Did my suggestion of copying the value to `tmp` not help?

Comment: No, it failed.  I tried it previously.  Using straight numeric values works correctly.  I fail to see how the application is causing the problem in the object execution, although it wouldn't surprise me if you knew the other problems I've had with it.

Comment: @Jason, I've added another possible route in my answer.

Comment: If your alternative route works, than this: `update1 =  SwfWindow("NextGen File Maintenance").SwfWindow("SIM Library Configuration").SwfObject("spreadCtl").Object.ActiveSheet.GetValue((x),2)` should work too. By adding parenthesis around x, it is evaluated before it is 'send' to the GetValue method.

Comment: @AutomatedChaos your solution works.  Adding the parenthesis around x is my preferred solution.  Thanks guys.